# Rising buildings animation ArcGIS Pro?

Tags: arcgis-pro, animation

If it is possible to create an animation in ArcGIS Pro with buildings rising up ( having the building footprints and DSM of the area as available data), then how do I do it?

Answer (score 1):

For the terrain, I would consider draping the raster over an elevation dataset (https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/mapping/layer-properties/define-height-characteristics-for-layers.htm). And for the 3d objects, I would consider ArcGIS Pro's preset layers (https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/mapping/layer-properties/preset-layers.htm) or for the architecture, I would try using Esri's CityEngine software, which utilizes rule packages to automatically generate buildings are a macroscale (https://doc.arcgis.com/en/cityengine/latest/help/help-cga-modeling-overview.htm). Another option for other objects like vehicles or miscellaneous structures could be importing them from other 3D software like SketchUp (https://3dwarehouse.sketchup.com/) or Autodesk (https://community.esri.com/external-link.jspa?url=https%3A%2F%2Fgallery.autodesk.com%2F). Fortunately,  different 3D formats are cross-platform compatible, but my experience is mostly limited to importing using Collada and Multipatch files into ArcGIS Pro.

As for animations, I would explore the Animation tab (https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/mapping/animation/overview-of-animation.htm) and the How Tos on Esri's documentaiton (https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/mapping/animation/animation-how-to-videos.htm). Their "Animate through time" page looks particularly interesting for ways to display statistical analyses.